# Call 64 bit Dll in my project 32 bit VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a Dll 64 bit and I need to call it from 32 bit c++ project ?
I try it and I get this problem :

```
error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
```

any idea please ?
Thanks

Comment: You can't do that directly. You'll have to use an intermediary, like an out-of-proc COM server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not allowed. You cannot directly link a 64 bit DLL to a 32 bit executable.

You should look into interprocess communication on windows. There are many ways to do it, of which I personally like Memory Mapped Files the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix 64-bit and 32-bit code in the same process. You'll have to compile your project in 64 bit, or create a new process of type 64 bit and and load the 64 bit dll there.